# what is the reason for java.lang.stackoverflowerror in this code?

Tags: java, recursion

what is the reason that i am getting java.lang.stackoverflowerror after running this code?

```
class recursion {       
    public static int func(int n) {             
        int result;             
        result = func (n - 1);             
        return result; 
    } 
}  

class Output {         
    public static void main(String args[]) {             
        recursion obj = new recursion(); 
        System.out.print(obj.func(12)); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: There is no base case

Answer (score 7):

You have no stopping condition.
You always call `func (n - 1)`, and therefore get an infinite chain of recursive calls until the stack overflows.

A proper recursive method must have a stopping condition. For example, the stopping condition may be when n reaches 0 :

```
public static  int func (int n) {   
    if (n <= 0)
        return 1;          
    int result = func (n - 1);             
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: leave the mortals answer the easy ones ;)

Answer (score 0):

When is the method func stopping?

You are calling it with `12` and then is going back to an infinite recursion.

On an unrelated note: you should take a look at the Java code conventions

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no limit (end point) for the recursive function call.
Try this -

```
class recursion 
{ 
    public static int func (int n) 
    { 
        int result = 0; 
        if(n > 0)
            result = func (n - 1);
        return result; 
    } 
}
class Output 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {  
        System.out.print(recursion.func(12)); 
    } 
}
```

You should call static function with class name.